# Undereating not hungry

Tags: diet, food, eating-habits

I log my food intake on [CHRON-O-Meter](https://cronometer.com/) and it comes out with 1500 calories. I am a 15 year old who is 180 cm tall and underweight, borderline healthy. However I am rarely hungry. Is this alright?

Ps. I am not sedentary, I walk a lot throughout the day.

Comment: If you're worried about being underweight, you'd be better off talking to a medical professional. If you want to put on some weight, then eating and appetite can be trained just like exercise, try and eat a little more each day until you're eating at the calories you think you should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Losing/gaining weight often has to do with battling hunger.

Overweight people who want to lose weight, will have to refrain from eating when they ARE hungry.

Underweight people who want to gain weight, will have to eat when they are NOT hungry.

Don't blame your appetite. Overcome it instead.